# Use of "did" in a negative sentence

Tags: word-usage, negation

Mark Knopfler in one of his famous songs says something like

> you never did have the intelligence to use (...).

I am a bit puzzled by the use of "did" here.

Is "did" emphasising the concept as in affirmative sentences? Or is that some kind of different construction?

Comment: Hello, Gibbs. Yes, 'did' here would be stressed in speech (subtly perhaps if the speaker were being sarcastic rather than exasperated) to emphasise the put-down.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @EdwinAshworth. I agree, it is however difficult for me to understand the sarcasm in this context, especially because it's a song...

Comment: I'm just addressing the general usages, Gibbs. Actual nuances in lyrics are expressly off-topic on ELU as too subjective to call.

Comment: If it is sarcastic it will depend on the context.

Comment: It's just an [emphatic *do*](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-emphatic-do-1690590). It's an emphatic version of *You never had the intelligence...* The same would be true in the positive: *You always **did** have the intelligence...*

Comment: @TinfoilHat this is exactly what I thought, thanks for confirming.

Comment: Note that in song lyrics sometimes a specific wording is chosen more for its rhythm than for its literal meaning. (I'm not saying that's what happened in this example, though certainly rhythm was a factor.)

Comment: "Did" can be used like this when referring to oneself as well, and not always negatively. Think of the song "Busy Doing Nothing" with the line "I'd like to be unhappy but I never _did have_ the time".